# Criar mascara para rg C#

Tags: c#

Gostaria de saber se tem como eu fazer aparecer a mascara feito através do código no meu form? E de qual modo seria, não está aparecendo no meu form o jeito que estou fazendo. No caso eu não sei se estaria colocando na posição correta.

```
if (mtbRG.Text.Length == 9)

{
   mtbRG.Mask = "00.000.000-0";
}
```

Comment: Acredito que RG não teria uma máscara, sendo que existem diversos formatos possíveis. Já vi RG que tinha caracteres no final, não sei bem ao certo o motivo, mas tinha. Acredito que RG deva ser um campo livre, diferentemente de CPF, por exemplo.

Comment: Entendi .. vou dar uma pesquisada obrigado